# $A:V\to V^*$ - question about $A$ being demicontinuous

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $V$ be a separable and reflexive Banach space. Consider operator $A:[0,T]\times V\to V^*$. The following hypothesis is on the data:

$A(t,\cdot)$ is demicontinuous on $V$ for a.e. $t\in (0,T)$. Is being demicontinuous equivalent to saying that $A$ is continuous as a mapping from $X$ to $(w^*-X^*)$ i.e.,  if $v_n\to v$ in $V$, then $$\langle A(t,v_n(t));\varphi(t)\rangle_{V^*\times V}\to \langle A(t,v(t));\varphi(t)\rangle_{V^*\times V}$$ 
for all $\varphi(t)$ and a.e. $t\in (0,T)$?

As far as I know, if a sequance $(l_n)\subset V^*$ is convergent in $(w^*-X^*)$, that means that there is some $l\in V^*$ and $$l_n(x)\to l(x)$$ for all $x\in V$. If I denote $l_n=A(t,v_n)$ ($t$ is fixed), then how to deduce that $l=A(t, v)$?